# Hazelcast: can I configure a hazelcast client to connect only to a single lite member of the cluster?

Tags: hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast cluster formed of 2 full members and a Lite member, multicast enabled. I want to connect multiple Hazelcast (.NET) clients exclusively to the Hazelcast Lite member. The thing is that even if I configure the address and port of this Lite member on the client side I still see connections from the client to the other 2 Hazelcast full cluster members:

```
<hazelcast-client>
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>10.28.0.106:5701</address>
        </cluster-members>
    </network>
    ...
</hazelcast-client>
```

Can this be done?

The idea is to have the Lite member store a large amount of mostly read-only data (near-client will be enabled on the Lite member) and will be running on the same machine as the clients so the access will be much faster than client->cluster connections.

Let's ignore the fact that this Lite member becomes a single point of failure here, the system as whole won't be impacted.

Comment: I don't think I got any of the initial idea. I seem to miss an important fact. I got that you want to have a lite member on the same host as a client. The client only connects to the lite member but the light member will connect to all other members. You want to add an extra network hop for no reason, with no viable use and no saving in network connections :-) I really have to miss something from the idea, can you please clarify? PS: below groupconfig thing won't work

Comment: @noctarius: clients will only connect to the lite member indeed, but the lite member will NOT need to connect to the cluster members. At least not frequently, as this lite member will load a very large amount of data from the cluster at once, most likely on start-up (or configuring near-client). This is mostly read-only data so invalidation will occur very infrequently in the lite member. The client host is running about 32 processes, all connecting to the lite member which runs on the same host. So for most of the time these 32 processes will only connect locally to the lite member.

Comment: @noctarius: I haven't got the chance to test yet groupconfig - with the details I added above, do you still think it won't work?

Comment: A lite member is a cluster member that doesn't store any data. Therefore your "lite member" would most probably be a client that disconnects after reading all the data into the local cache. I would assume this to be a combination of a Hazelcast client (reading data from the cluster) and a local EHcache storing the data in process. I still don't understand what you think is the use case for the lite member in this case :) PS: nope still don't think it will work. It will form two clusters, one for the data members and the lite member is alone and can NEVER access the other cluster, not a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set smart routing to false on client and only configure lite member on client side, client will be connected to lite member only. 
See http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-smart-routing

But when that lite member dies, client will connect to one of the other nodes. If you want your client to shutdown when it disconnects from lite member, you can use lifecycle listener on client side. When you see LifecycleEvent.LifecycleState.CLIENT_DISCONNECTED event call hazelcastClient.shutdown().

Comment: Disabling smart routing appears to work indeed, thanks!
I'm setting this as the accepted answer as it relates exactly to the question. In the meantime however I've given up on the Lite member and went with a different configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `GroupConfig` for this purpose. 
From JavaDoc:

> With groups it is possible to create multiple clusters where each cluster has its own group and doesn't interfere with other clusters.

You should declare group config for the client (2 times - for Lite member and full members) and for Lite & full members correspondingly.

```
<group>
    <name>liteGroup</name>
    <password>pswd1</password>
<group>
<group>
    <name>fullGroup</name>
    <password>pswd2</password>
<group>
```

Look at [Group Config Doc](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/groupconfiguration.html)

Feel free to contact me if you have any questions.

Comment: I see, thanks for the hint, will certainly test GroupConfig, seems like it should do the job.